# What is the use of False in delete() function in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm, django-views

I'm working on code refactoring of django project which was like 4 years old and came across a syntax which confused me.

They passed a boolean parameter `False` to django ORM like `object.delete(False)`.

I checked the docs for `delete()` function in django ORM. But couldn't find `False` parameter to it.

And there is no method overriding in Django Model for `delete()` method.

What is this `False` parameter for?

**`Django version: 1.11.29`**

Comment: You could be more precise about Django version for instance also you could check base delete() implementation yourself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First parameter is using and there is no difference between setting it to False or by default to None

From [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.1.x/django/db/models/base.py#L583)

```
def delete(self, using=None, keep_parents=False):
    using = using or router.db_for_write(self.__class__, instance=self)
    assert self._get_pk_val() is not None, (
        "%s object can't be deleted because its %s attribute is set to None." %
        (self._meta.object_name, self._meta.pk.attname)
    )

    collector = Collector(using=using)
    collector.collect([self], keep_parents=keep_parents)
    return collector.delete()
```

Answer (score 1):

Was it by any chance the second parameter being passed in? Or as kwargs `keep_parents=False`?

If so you can refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete

Edit: Noticed that you added the Django version which is really helpful.
I don't think anything has changed related to `delete` since then (maybe except `on_delete` for the foreign key definitions is required)